# How does Delphi round Currency during multiplication

Tags: delphi, rounding

```
rate : Currency;
mod1 : Currency;
mod2 : Currency;
mod_rate : Currency;

rate := 29.90;
mod1 := 0.95;
mod2 := 1.39;

mod_rate := rate * mod1 * mod2;
```

If you perform this calculation on a calculator you get a value of `39.45295`.  Since Delphi's `Currency` datatype is only precise to 4 decimals it internally rounds the value.  My testing indicates that it uses Banker's rounding so that mod_rate should contain a value of `39.4530`, however in this particular case it truncates to `39.4529`.

I have 40,000 of these calculations and all are correct except the above. Here is an example that rounds up:

```
rate := 32.25;
mod1 := 0.90;
mod2 := 1.15;
```

This equals `33.37875` on a calculator and according to Banker's rounding would go to `33.3788`, which is what Delphi does.

Could someone shed some light as to what Delphi is doing here?

Comment: My guess is that 39.4595 is not exactly representable in floating point. Nothing wrong with rounding but with representability. Use decimal arithmetic instead of currency.

Comment: Currency is a fixed point datatype.  Unless multiplying two Currencies yields a float.

Comment: @Chet: `Currency` values are internally stored as 64-bit integers that have been multiplied by 10000 to remove decimals, but math performed on `Currency` values use floating point math instructions on those integers.

Comment: You can see the floating point representation of 39.45295 here: [What is the exact value of a floating-point variable?](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=39.45295). The extended precision value is below 39.45295, hence the rounding downwards.

Comment: You can use [`System.Math.SetRoundMode()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.SetRoundMode) to control how floating-point values, including `Currency`, are rounded.

Comment: @Remy How would that help?

Comment: Are all 64 bit numbers processed using the FPU? Seems to defeat the purpose of fixed point.

Comment: Only currency values are processed in the fpu.

Comment: So if I need this to calculate "right" I should use longs instead, multiply my values by 10,000 to do my calculation, and divide by 10,000 before returning the value as Currency?

Comment: Have a look at [Decimals](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/decimals.html), which is a library that handles float values with higher precision, albeit at the cost of performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Currency` calculations takes place in the fpu with extended precision, even though the currency itself is a 64 bit integer value.

The problem you have is with floating point binary representation, rather than rounding errors.
You can see the floating point representation of 39.45295 here: [What is the exact value of a floating-point variable?](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=39.45295)

> 39.45295 = + 39.45294 99999 99999 99845 67899 95771 03240 88111 51981 35375 97656 25

The extended precision value is below 39.45295, hence the rounding downwards.

Use a decimal arithmetic library instead to avoid these kind of errors.

---

To see that the floating point arithmetic is performed in the fpu for `currency` calculations, here is a disassembly:

```
mod_rate := rate * mod1 * mod2;
0041D566 DF2D20584200     fild qword ptr [$00425820]
0041D56C DF2D28584200     fild qword ptr [$00425828]
0041D572 DEC9             fmulp st(1)
0041D574 DF2D30584200     fild qword ptr [$00425830]
0041D57A DEC9             fmulp st(1)
0041D57C D835C4D54100     fdiv dword ptr [$0041d5c4]
0041D582 DF3D38584200     fistp qword ptr [$00425838]
0041D588 9B               wait
```

`fmulp` and `fdiv` are done with extended precision.
If integer operations had been used, the instructions would have been `fimul` and `fidiv`.

Comment: I'm about ready to accept this answer. Can you cite some documentation that indicates that Delphi processes Currency as floating point?

Comment: Yeah, I was going to analyze the assembly to verify, thanks for posting it.

Comment: 801 / 2 (both currencies) results in 400.5.  According to this (http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=400.5) that is exactly representable in floating point.  Yet, that rounds up to 401.  I'm sure it is still a FP issue, but it is annoying.

Comment: `mod1 := 801.0;
  mod2 := 2.0;
  mod_rate := mod1/mod2;` results in 400.5 on my computer with currency variables. `Round(mod_rate)` results in 400.0.

Comment: I reviewed the code more thoroughly, the 801 is an integer.